# Lückentext: Jugend vs Jugendliche

Tags: grammar-identification, grammaticality

> Rückläufige Geburtenraten im deutschen Bundesgebiet haben das Bundesministerium für Familie, Senioren, Frauen und Jug(end) zur Einführung des sogenannten Elterngeldes veranlasst.

The braceketted part was deleted, and I was asked to fill it in. I put as "liche" giving Jugendliche. Are both equivalent, or is there any reason that Jugend is preferred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this is the official title of the ministery, there is only one correct option, namely the official version being

> Bundesministerium für Familie, Senioren, Frauen und Jugend

Besides the official title of the ministery, in general I'd say that *Jugendliche* is referring to the members of the group while *Jugend* is referring to the group itself. Needless to mention that *Jugend* of course also has the (main) meaning "youth, the state of being young".

Comment: Jugendliche is informal?

Comment: @trystwithfreedom It is not informal. The ministery just happens to have the literal "Jugend" in its name.

Comment: Da von *Frauen*, nicht von *Weiblichkeit* zuvor die Rede ist, sowie von *Senioren*, nicht *Alter*, wäre *Jugendliche* die konsequente Folge. Offenbar entweder eine Fangfrage, oder eine Frage zum Allgemeinwissen.

Comment: Logically “Jugendliche” would have been better, like “Frauen”. But if that’s the name of the ministry then it’s the name.